# cookie creation with full domain name

Tags: c#, cookies, dns

I am trying to create cookie with domain : ausserver.company.com and it is not getting created.
I tried with company.com and it works.

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("cookie name");
 cookie.Domain = "auscc.company.com";
 Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

I also did see that there are couple of cookies like JSESSIONID which has cookie host = "auscc.company.com".
I dont know how are they created?

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is this :

You can only set the domain to yourself (the current site) and sub-domains of yourself, for security reasons. You can't set cookies for arbitrary sites.

For example :

abc.com can write cookies to abc.com, foo.abc.com and *.abc.com; it cannot write cookies for xyz.com at all.

Comment: I think you are right. Because that JESSIONID was created by abc.com. But I am trying to create xyz.abc.com. Do you think that is also not possible?

Comment: I think browser doesn't allow that.